# SQL - Getting Updated Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I use Sql Server 2008.

I have a table that generates ID.
I want to retrieve the generated ID and store it in a bigint variable.
How can I do it?

Here is the Stored Proc that gives the ID as result set. But I  cannot store it in a bigint variable.

```
ALTER PROC SCN.TRANSACTION_UNIQUE_ID_SELECT
AS

UPDATE COR.TRANSACTION_UNIQUE_ID
SET ID = ID + 1

OUTPUT INSERTED.ID AS ID
```

Comment: is there more to this?  a 'sequence' would be a built-in alternative.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `output` you can;

```
declare @ID table (ID bigint)

update the_table
  set ID = ID + 1
output INSERTED.ID into @ID

declare @bi bigint = (select ID from @ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

The BigInt should be an identity insert column, this will make SQL Server automatically generate bigints in sequence for you.  Just pass the rowID as an OUTPUT parameter and set it before the procedure ends after the insert/update.

Then you can read it coming back and set it as needed.

The stored procedure could look something like this (I've only included the rowID for clarity):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Sample].[Save] 
    (

     @rowID bigint OUTPUT

    )
AS
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON

 --Do your insert/update here


 --Set the RowID
 SET @rowID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

 END
```

Answer (score 0):

That `UPDATE` looks fishy...it will increment every `ID` in your table by one, no?

Anyway, variables have an `@sign`, so just `SET @myvar = ...whatever...`

Answer (score 0):

Use `OUTPUT INTO`:

```
DECLARE @TblID TABLE ( ID int )

UPDATE COR.TRANSACTION_UNIQUE_ID
SET ID = ID + 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @TblID (ID) --the output values will be inserted 
                                    --into @TblID table-variable
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @id BIGINT
EXEC @id = SCN.TRANSACTION_UNIQUE_ID_SELECT
```

Comment: It will set the return-value from procedure to @id, but not the resultset.